# De Morgan's laws in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, demorgans-law

I am writing a shell script. I have a `getopts` case statement initally and then I have another case statement that simply checks `$@`. In the second case statement I check if the user has typed --update or --uninstall.

In the first getopts case statement I have an error case:

```bash
"?") if  [[ $@ -ne "--uninstall" ]] && [[ $@ -ne "--update" ]]; then
     echo "Invalid option"
```

However it's not working as expected. I'm familiar with De Morgan's laws where !(A && B) = !A || !B and vice verrsa however this is not working in my script.

The expected behaviour would be I can run my script with the argument --uninstall or --update and run those functions. However not matter the configuration I have this if statement at best I can get one of the functions to run but not the other.

In the snippet I posted above running it with --uninstall it doesn't work, however --update works.

Comment: `-ne` is for integer comparison. For string comparison use `==`.

Comment: I don't think you want an equality test either; if there's more than one argument/option, `$@` will expand to the entire list, not just a single item. To do this right, you need to iterate over the arguments and compare each one individually (and you shouldn't be trying to do this in a `getopts` loop. In fact, if your script accepts long options, you shouldn't really use `getopts` at all.

Comment: Also be careful: De Morgans law applies to boolean logic. You don't have boolean operators here. `A && B`  simply means: Run the command `A`, and if the exit status is zero, also run command `B`.